# is there an awk column offset?

Tags: debian, awk, partition

I am trying to create a command that works with the output to check the partition type and name. I have just discovered a solution using `awk` or perhaps `sfdisk`?

Here's my base output:

```
root@debian:/home/si# sudo sfdisk -l /dev/sda --quiet | awk '{print $0}'
Périphérique Amorçage   Début      Fin Secteurs Taille Id Type     
/dev/sda1    *           2048  2000895  1998848   976M 83 Linux    
/dev/sda2             2000896 86962175 84961280  40,5G 8e LVM Linux
```

Now let's filter on column `$1` ,`$7` and `$8`

```
root@debian:/home/si# sudo sfdisk -l /dev/sda --quiet | awk '{print $1, $7, $8}'
Périphérique Id Type  
/dev/sda1 83 Linux    
/dev/sda2 LVM Linux
```

It seems there's an offset on column because `LVM` value on `/dev/sda2` should belong to the `Type` column, so the `$8` column if I'm right.

How does `awk` displays the columns ? Is there any filter I miss ?

In my mind, the output columns display should be like (`|` manually add)

```
$1           |      $2  |     $3   |   $4     |    $5    |   $6   | $7 | $8
Périphérique | Amorçage |  Début   |   Fin    | Secteurs | Taille | Id | Type     
/dev/sda1    |*         |  2048    | 2000895  |  1998848 |  976M  | 83 | Linux    
/dev/sda2    |          |  2000896 | 86962175 |84961280  | 40,5G  | 8e | LVM Linux
```

Comment: Are your columns **really** sometimes left-aligned (Périphérique Amorçage Type) and sometimes right-aligned (Début      Fin Secteurs Taille)?

Comment: I thought it was but it seems not as someone mentionned in the answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your picture is erroneous. The last line would look like this:

```
      1      |     2   |    3     |     4    |    5   |  6 |  7  | 8
/dev/sda2    | 2000896 | 86962175 |84961280  | 40,5G  | 8e | LVM | Linux
```

Because some of your fields contain more whitespace than others, and some lines are missing certain columns, trying to extract data by field number is going to be tricky. Consider using the JSON output available from `sfdisk` that largely avoid these problems:

```
sudo sfdisk -J /dev/nvme0n1 |
  jq -r '.partitiontable.partitions[]|[.node, .size, .type]|@tsv'
```

That would output something like (on my system):

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1  409600  C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
/dev/nvme0n1p2  2097152 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4
/dev/nvme0n1p3  493076480   E6D6D379-F507-44C2-A23C-238F2A3DF928
```

You'll notice that this uses UUIDs to identify partition types rather than names, so you may need to map that back to something human readable depending on your goals.

Comment: Hey ! thanks a lot for all of this knowledge. I really thought that awk detect "column header"-like. I wasn't aware it was based on space separator. You absolutely right, in my case the JSON output is far easier, thanks again for this advice !

Answer (score 6):

The output of `sfdisk` is formatted by physical columns rather than logical fields.

To parse it with Awk, use GNU Awk. GNU Awk has support for parsing fixed columns.

This works with my installation of `sfdisk`:

```
$ sudo sfdisk -l /dev/sda --quiet | gawk -v OFS="|" -v FIELDWIDTHS='11 4 9 9 9 6 3 40'  '$1=$1'
Device     |Boot|    Start|      End|  Sectors|  Size| Id| Type
/dev/sda1  |*   |     2048| 50427903| 50425856|   24G| 83| Linux
/dev/sda2  |    | 50429950| 52426751|  1996802|  975M|  5| Extended
/dev/sda5  |    | 50429952| 52426751|  1996800|  975M| 82| Linux swap / Solaris
```

Note that the fields are not trimmed of whitespace.

Another trick we can play is to take advantage of the only field being missing is the boot flag `*`. We can stick some alternative character in its place, like `!` and then get Awk to re-parse the record using `$1=$1`:

```
$ sudo sfdisk -l /dev/sda --quiet  | awk -v OFS="," 'NR > 1 && $2 != "*" { $0=substr($0, 1, 11) "!" substr($0, 13) } ; $1=$1'
Device,Boot,Start,End,Sectors,Size,Id,Type
/dev/sda1,*,2048,50427903,50425856,24G,83,Linux
/dev/sda2,!,50429950,52426751,1996802,975M,5,Extended
/dev/sda5,!,50429952,52426751,1996800,975M,82,Linux,swap,/,Solaris
```

We no longer have spurious blanks, but on the downside, the type field gets munged into fields, of course; if it is needed in one piece there are ways.

Comment: Pretty ingenious ! i'll have a look at gawk, thanks a lot !